# JPA query with OneToOne lazy

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this structure of object

```
@Entity
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long memberId;

    private String name;

    private boolean man;

    private String address;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private City city;

    private String postalCode;

    private String phone1;

    private String phone2;

    private LocalDate birthdate;

    private String email;

    private String emergencyContactName;

    private String emergencyPhone;

    private String paymentGatewayKey;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Contract> contracs;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Commerce commerce;
}


@Entity
public class Contract {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long contractId;

    private BigDecimal price;

    private int frequency;

    private int term;

    private LocalDate startDate;

    private LocalDate endDate;

    private int numberOfPayment;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusEnum status;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "contract")
    private List<Payment> payments;

    @ManyToOne
    private Member member;
}

@Entity
public class Payment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long paymentId;

    private BigDecimal price;

    private LocalDate date;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusEnum status;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PaymentModeEnum paymentMode;

    @ManyToOne
    private Contract contract;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Operation> operations;

}
```

is it possible from a member query to get only the needed contract, payment, city and commerce info?

If member have many contract... i want to get only contract #2...

I started this query but city and commerce are lazy and i don't know what to do with theses fields.

```
select m from Member m inner join fetch m.contracs c inner join fetch c.payments p where c.contractId = :contractId
```

Comment: If a member has many contracts then you do a query for Contract so you just pull back the one you want. You do NOT pull back a Member and access the contracts field (or load that field of a Member).

Comment: ok so this query is not good?

Comment: does that query select a Contract? No. So you'll get loading of all elements of the collection ... as my comment says. Have you actually tried it?